# Subset and replace with NA if missing

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the data frame that I would like to subset based on the `Id==8210`.
As there is no 'betweenesscentrality' for `Id==8210`, how can have the `bar_8221` filled with NA? I tried `ifelse` but is not working. Any suggestions?

Sample code:

```
bar_8221 <- subset(x3n, x3n$Id== "8221")
```

Sample data:

```
x3n<-structure(list(Id = c(110, 3110, 210, 3130, 310, 1110, 5140, 
8210, 9360, 9990, 3310, 8110, 8219, 3210, 7241, 3240, 3320, 3611, 
3710, 8212), betweenesscentrality = c(0.102339, 0.395224, 0.048246, 
0.128168, 0.052632, 0.615497, 0, 0.074561, 0.219298, 0.052632, 
0.140351, 0.018519, 0.018519, 0.173977, 0.176901, 0.064327, 0.024366, 
0, 0.04386, 0.074561)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Possible outputs for `bar_8221`

without `8221`

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Do you want to keep al the IDs, but replace **between...** with NA when the ID isn't equal to 8221? Or do you want to replace the IDs with NA when the ID isn't equal to 8221?

Comment: @user11418708, it is still not clear what you actually want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understand:

```
MyFunction <- function(data, ID){
  if(ID %in% x3n$Id){
    output <- data %>% 
      filter(Id == ID)
  } else{
    output <- data.frame(ID = ID,
                         Value = NA)
  }
  output
}
```

`MyFunction(x3n, 8221)` return what you expected, but be careful: this code isn't well-written and can be improved. Indeed: the data imput must be called x3n and the Id column must be the first one **and** written 'Id'.

Comment: If you could be even more precise with your request, I will be able to give a more-well-structured program :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function with `match` -

```
get_value <- function(x) x3n$betweenesscentrality[match(x, x3n$Id)]

get_value(8210)
#[1] 0.074561
get_value(8221)
#[1] NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```r
require(dplyr)

ID <- 310

if (nrow(subset(x3n, x3n$Id== ID)) == 0) tibble('Id_{ID}' := NA) else tibble('Id_{ID}' := filter(x3n, Id == ID) %>% pull(betweenesscentrality)) 
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   Id_310
#>    <dbl>
#> 1 0.0526

ID <- 8221

if (nrow(subset(x3n, x3n$Id== ID)) == 0) tibble('Id_{ID}' := NA) else tibble('Id_{ID}' := filter(x3n, Id == ID) %>% pull(betweenesscentrality)) 
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   Id_8221
#>   <lgl>  
#> 1 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>